# Generate pytest-html report per module in a session

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I understand that the HTML report is written in the `pytest_sessionfinish` hookimpl ([src](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html/blob/master/src/pytest_html/html_report.py)). Which if i run multiple modules in one session, it will create only one report.
However, i would want to have one report for each module ran.

With my conftest.py containing:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    script_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(lib_programname.get_path_executed_script()))[0]
    if not os.path.exists('reports'):
        os.makedirs('reports')
    config.option.htmlpath = 'reports/'+ 'report_' + script_name + ".html"
    config.option.self_contained_html = True
```

If i run: `pytest .\test_One.py .\test_Two.py`. It generates only one html file, `report_test_One.html` containing both module results.
However, is there a way i could add in on my conftest.py that it will create reports for each module ran instead of one per session? i.e. `report_test_One.html`, `report_test_Two.html`?

Comment: The report generation is bound to a session, reading the info about start time or the amount of total/passed/failed tests, so the short answer is no. As a workaround, you can invoke `pytest` twice, as in `pytest test_One.py --html=report-one.html; pytest test_Two.py --html=report-two.html`.